# Why does false[0] not throw an error for undefined offset?

Tags: php, php-7.1

**Why does false[0] not throw an `undefined offset` error?**
(and should I count on this behavior)

*Background Story*

I am sending the `options` object of a Vuetify datatable component to a php backend.  The backend is slim3.

I noticed that the query parameter for sortDesc looked like: `api/search/order?sortDesc[]=true`

I didn't even know you could pass an array in a URL parameter! It's an array because multisort is possible, but I will never use it.  Well, there are three possibilities being: `sortDesc[0]=true`, `sortDesc[0]=false`, and `sortDesc` not present at all.  I figured out the parameter may not be present after I made the change to my code to look at the zero index of the parameter like this:

```
$options['orderDir'] = $request->
    getQueryParam('sortDesc', $default = false)[0] ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
```

I realize this isn't the best way to do this parameter init/check, but now I'm wondering why I'm not getting an exception when the parameter isn't present, so I made a test an executed the code `echo false[0];` and sure enough, no error.

These also do not throw an error

```
echo 'some thing' . false[0]
echo 'some thing' . false[20]
echo false[-10]
echo 'some thing' . true[0]
```

I could not find any documentation or write up detailing this behavior and was wondering if anyone had some incite. Especially whether I should count on this behavior.

Comment: You are correct. My search skills are apparently lacking!

Comment: Don't delete this question as it will only help to flesh out the search terms :)

Comment: FYI: this issue will be fixed with PHP 7.4, it will throw an `E_WARNING` message, see more [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47704)